# Salesforce Apex to update SFMC Subscriber status

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, update, subscriber, status

I have to write apex code on salesforce service/sales cloud to update dynamic list of 
Subscribers status on Marketing cloud (SFMC), I will be having list of contactkey from marketing cloud (SOQL query for an object)

I have done some search and found this is achievable using Integration with Marketing Cloud using SOAP API (looks like REST is not supported to update subscriber status)

The link below has some c# and Java examples (but not Apex code)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/update.htm

And I have some experience on REST calls, but new to SOAP integration.
(I have postman client and have tested rest successfully)

Need help step by step from having the correct endpoints, and creating dynamic soap envelop etc using Apex code

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@A Iqbal try this one create two classes one is **testet** class and second one is **testintegration** class this is code

```
   public with sharing class testet
         {  
 public static String getHeader2()
   {
     string soapMessage='';
     soapMessage='<soapenv:Header>';
  soapMessage+='<Security xmlns="'+'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 
 200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'+'">';           
 soapMessage+='<UsernameToken>';
            soapMessage+='<Username>'+'mc username here'+'</Username>';
            soapMessage+='<Password>'+'****'+'</Password>';
        soapMessage+='</UsernameToken>';
        soapMessage+='</Security>';
      soapMessage+='</soapenv:Header>';



    return soapMessage;
  }
public static Dom.Document processRequest(String etend, String respone, String action) {
    Dom.Document doc;
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    req.setHeader('SOAPAction', action);
    req.setEndpoint(etend);
    req.setBody(respone);
    HttpResponse res;

        res = h.send(req);   
        System.debug('res:'+res.getBody());

    return doc;
    }
 }
  ---------------------------------------------
 Second class

         public with sharing class testintegration
          {
       public static string endpoint;
       public static string partnerurl= 'http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI';
    public static string soapurl= '<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:par="'+partnerurl+'" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
 instance">';
    @future(callout=true)
public static void sendData()
{
    endpoint ='https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx';
    String soapMessage = '';
       soapMessage+=soapurl;
      soapMessage+=testet.getHeader2();


           soapMessage+='<soapenv:Body>';
                soapMessage+='<UpdateRequest xmlns="'+partnerurl+'">';

                   soapMessage+='<Options>';
                   soapMessage+='<SaveOptions>';
                   soapMessage+='<SaveOption>';
                   soapMessage+='<PropertyName>'+'*'+'</PropertyName>';
                   soapMessage+='<SaveAction>'+'UpdateAdd'+'</SaveAction>';
                   soapMessage+='</SaveOption>';                                                                                                                          
                    soapMessage+='</SaveOptions>';
                    soapMessage+='</Options>';
                soapMessage+='<Client>';
                       soapMessage+='<ID>'+*****+'</ID>';
                       soapMessage+='</Client>';  
                        soapMessage+='<Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">';

                            soapMessage+='<EmailAddress>'+'*****'+'</EmailAddress>';

                            soapMessage+='<SubscriberKey>'+'****'+'</SubscriberKey>';
                        soapMessage+='<Attributes>'; 
                    soapMessage+='<Name>Email Address</Name><Value>'+'*****'+'</Value>';                            
                    soapMessage+='</Attributes>';
                    soapMessage+='<Status>'+'Unsubscribed'+'</Status>';
                    soapMessage+='</Objects>';
                soapMessage+='</UpdateRequest>';
           soapMessage+='</soapenv:Body>';
       soapMessage+='</soapenv:Envelope>';
       System.debug('ReqMessage:'+soapMessage);


      Dom.document response = Etprocess.processRequest(endpoint, soapMessage, 'Update');
      System.debug('Response:'); 
}
  }
```

Comment: create remote site settings in sales force like this this is endpoint 
     https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx

Comment: thanks for the answer, will try this and update here

Comment: this works with some minor changes

Answer (score 1):

//My working code that might help others
//Note:Please create a class and insert below 2 methods
//Calling Marketing Cloud 'UpdateRequest' to update subscriber status
//Please write code to get access token (or look for a sample)

```
public static HttpResponse updateMCSubscriber(String email,String subscriberKey, String listId, String status, String action){

    string soapEndpoint='https://<YOURMCINSTANCE>.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx';

    //----------------------------------note below--------------
    //Please write code to get the access token here alternatively you can use username and password as as show by "pkharries"
    string token='';//getToken();

    String soapEnvelopeTemplate = '<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<Header>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<fueloauth>'+token+'</fueloauth>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='</Header>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<Body>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<EmailAddress>'+email+'</EmailAddress>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<SubscriberKey>'+subscriberKey+'</SubscriberKey>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<Lists>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<ID>'+listId+'</ID>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<Status>'+status+'</Status>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='<Action>'+action+'</Action>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='</Lists>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='</Objects>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='</UpdateRequest>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='</Body>';
    soapEnvelopeTemplate+='</Envelope>';

    String body = String.format(soapEnvelopeTemplate, new String[]{token, email,subscriberKey, listId, status, action});
    //System.debug('body:' + body);
    return makeHTTPXMLPost(soapEndpoint, body,action);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static HttpResponse makeHTTPXMLPost(String endPoint, String soapBody,String SOAPAction){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setTimeout(60000);
    req.setEndpoint(endPoint);  
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('SOAPAction',SOAPAction); 
    req.setHeader('Accept','text/xml');  
    req.setHeader('Content-type','text/xml');    
    req.setHeader('charset','UTF-8'); 
    req.setBody(soapBody);    
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    //return s.getBody();
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//code to test implementation

String email='askaslam@gmail.com';

string skey='0030N50001dsItqQAE';

String listId='71';
String status='Active';
String action='Update';

//status='Unsubscribed';

HttpResponse res=updateMCSubscriber(email, skey,listId, status, action);

System.debug('getStatus():' + res.getStatus());

System.debug('getStatusCode():' + res.getStatusCode());